# Creating a custom WP7 control with extra XAML parameters

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, controls

I want to create a control that inherits from TextBox, which has an attribute called 'Filler'. I have the basic control created (named GhostBox), so I can load it in to a sample project and see it on the designer, but I don't know how to create custom XAML parameters (such as Text and Width which already exist). Please explain how to add these?

Example:

```
<ghostbox:GhostBox Name="ghostBox1" Text=""  Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" Margin="0,80,0,0" Filler="Filler Text"/>
```

As you can see at the end of the tag, there is a Filler attribute. That's what I want to add, if I haven't made it clear enough.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called Dependency Properties. Have a read of [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) about them.